# Samba share only writable when chown for specific user set

Tags: 14.04, server, permissions, samba, shared-folders

I have a samba server running on a Ubuntu 14.04 server

I set up a samba share.

```
[Pictures]
writeable = yes
path = /mnt/data/share/Pictures
user = christian test
valid users = christian test
write list = christian test
```

The problem is that when I set the chown to this:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 nobody nogroup 4096 Jul 10 18:59 Pictures
```

I can access and read files but I am not able to edit/create/delete files/folders.

If I alter the chown to:

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 christian users   4096 Aug 15 22:03 Pictures
```

I can edit/create/delete. But only as user christian. User test is still not able to do anything.

Who should be the owner of the share folder to make sure that the permissions are set using the samba specific user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure you added both users using

```
 smbpasswd -a <username>
```

and also check permission of shared directory

```
 chmod 770 /mnt/data/share/Pictures
```

if you want to use any group then all users that you want to allow access shared directory should be member of that group.
create group using

```
groupadd smbuser
```

assign group to share directory

```
 chown :smbuser /mnt/data/share/Pictures
```

add user to group

```
usermod -G smbuser christian
usermod -G smbuser test
```

for more info [this link](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/using_samba/ch09.html)

Comment: Adding the users to the group seems to do the trick. I am now able to write/edit files and folders. But I can't delete them.

Comment: My bet. The file I tried to delete was created by me as root user directly via ssh. Therefore the permissions where off. Everything works now as it should. Thank you!